# Free From Mortal Sin

Tags: riddle

> I wasn't a proud man who pursued my wife before she was mine.
>
> I never thought I was better than the one she already had.
>
> I didn't sleep with every woman I knew.
>
> I didn't love a woman because I had to have her.
>
> I didn't <s>hate</s> [wasn't angry with] her for not wanting to be mine.
>
> I didn't have to have them all.
>
> I didn't destroy the place where we would stay.

What am I?

**Hint:**

> I have taken a very well known set of rules and applied it to a relationship.

Comment: ...What do you want me to do?

Comment: ...My what? I don't understand.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry, I have to fix my comment. The negation implies sanctity, which is inline with yours and the correct answer. The converse is more familiar territory.

Comment: @randal'thor, Thanks for the edit, but regarding the tag, in light of Mark's answer, wouldn't steganography be helpful?

Comment: @John Not sure why you ping me about it - it was JMP who removed the [steganography] tag! (But since you ask, IMO, it should be tagged [riddle] and not [steganography]: the solution is hidden within a cryptic descriptive verse, not an innocuous-looking message.)

Comment: @randal'thor, hahaha, yes, sorry. There are two separate edits. Hmm, even more curious. I guess thought that a count of a type would be helpful so I included that tag, but then of course I really didn't want someone to over-analyze it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although an answer has been accepted, it sounds like the intended answer was:

> Seven Virtues, which are the opposite of the Seven Deadly Sins

Comment: You're correct. +1.

Answer (score 3):

You are:

> The Seven Deadly Sins (or not): Pride, Envy, Sloth, Lust , Anger, Greed, Wrath

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Are you going to edit your answer too, or can I steal?

Comment: @bg6471; why, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @bg6471, it's too close to award to someone else. I'm accepting as is.

Comment: @John I've added what I believe was the intended answer